# How to force a type declaration to have at least one known parameter while the rest are unknown

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a function that accepts an object of any shape, but I want to be sure that the object always have a specific property of a given type.

```
function ofInterest(param: any){
   // do some computation using param's p property
   ... = param.p
}
```

That way calling function `ofInterest` with a parameter which does not have the desired property results in a type check error:

```
const param = {q: '', r: 0}

// this should be an error cause param does not have a property 'p'
ofInterest(param)
```

How can I declare `ofInterest`'s param?

Answer (score 0):

```
function ofInterest(param: {p: DesiredType} & any){
   // now we I'm totally sure that property 'p' exists in param
   ... = param.p
}
```

The trick is to define `param` as a union between the desired specific type(s) and `any`. That way we always know that the parameter have the expected property(ies) while we still give the client some freedom to use the function with objects of almost any shape.

Comment: Given that TypeScript is _structurally_, not _nominally_, typed, there is no need at all for `& any`. It's already the case that `function ofInterest(param: {p: DesiredType}){` would accept objects with other properties, except in cases where excess properties are checked (e.g. `ofInterest({ inline: "object" })`, but then why would you want to have excess props there?): https://tsplay.dev/wRGpvN

Answer (score 0):

You need to use generics in this case:

```js
function ofInterest<Param extends { p:any }>(param: Param){
   param.p // ok
}
```